# Why MySQL query is so slow with two WHEREs

Tags: mysql

i have a problem.
Within the time, i get much rows in mysql.

To Filter i want to get some informations.

This is my query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cases,
       SUM(`item_price`) AS preturile
  FROM cases
  WHERE opened = 1 AND
        trade_id = '1234'
```

It is very slow... needs 1.5 secs or something

If i kick out opened = 1, so it looks like that

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cases,
       SUM(`item_price`) AS preturile
  FROM cases
  WHERE trade_id = '1234'
```

The speed is fast and good! But i need that opened 1 in there... But why is that so slow?

opened is int(11) and has INDEX.

I dont know what i can do there, its so slow...

Comment: Did you try indexing on both columns?

Comment: What @ReazMurshed said. Also, [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) is your friend. Trying using it on each query to see the differences.

Comment: i dont had trade_id on index... that was it :/ :D

Comment: Execute [`analyze table cases`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html), then retry your slow query.

Answer (score 2):

be sure you have a proper index  eg a composite index on   the columns trade_id, opened

```
create index  myidx on cases ( trade_id, opened )
```